# Passing many variables from entry widgets to label widgets tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I am currently creating a program with gui that opens to a mainscreen with several buttons then quite a few cells(setup as blank label widgets) that need to be filled with data.

Several of the buttons will open a new window and prompt the user to enter data into entry widgets. I want to then take this data and insert it back into the label widgets on the mainscreen.

After lots of searching and attempts I have finaly determined that I can setup StringVar() variables that are set as the text variable imputs on the labels on the main page.

This issue with this is that is creates a large number of variables that have to be declared as global vairables both in the parent class of the main screen as well asin the function that runs when the button is pressed on the second screen to set the data into the mainscreen labels.

This code here sets up the variables in the parent class:

```
    global wgentry
    global woentry
    global dentry
    global tidentry
    global aventry
    global aaentry
    global bventry
    global baentry
    global cventry
    global caentry

    wgentry = tk.StringVar() 
    woentry = tk.StringVar()
    dentry = tk.StringVar()
    tidentry = tk.StringVar()
    aventry = tk.StringVar()
    aaentry = tk.StringVar()
    bventry = tk.StringVar()
    baentry = tk.StringVar()
    cventry = tk.StringVar()
    caentry = tk.StringVar()

    wgentry.set(returnlist[0])
    woentry.set(returnlist[0])
    dentry.set(returnlist[0])
    tidentry.set(returnlist[0])
    aventry.set(returnlist[0])
    aaentry.set(returnlist[0])
    bventry.set(returnlist[0])
    baentry.set(returnlist[0])
    cventry.set(returnlist[0])
    caentry.set(returnlist[0])
```

This code is then run in the button press function to change the values.

```
    global wgentry
    global woentry
    global dentry
    global tidentry
    global aventry
    global aaentry
    global bventry
    global baentry
    global cventry
    global caentry

    wgentry.set(workgroupentry.get())
    woentry.set(workorderentry.get())
    dentry.set(dateentry.get())
    tidentry.set(transidentry.get())
    aventry.set(avoltageentry.get())
    aaentry.set(aangleentry.get())
    bventry.set(bvoltageentry.get())
    baentry.set(bangleentry.get())
    cventry.set(cvoltageentry.get())
    caentry.set(cangleentry.get())
```

I have tried to cut down my code to get something working to post up but have been unsuccessful but simply I am just trying to find out wether there is a better way to have text update on a GUI. Maybe there is a different style of widget that can be updated easier or if there is possibly a function similar to StringVar() that works for lists and can simply reference a certain item within a list. As this is one part of the program and I am going to have to be doing this a lot more as I advance the program further.

Thanks

This image is the popup that the user puts the data into
[image]

This is the mainscreen when the inputted data from the user must be inserted
[image]

Comment: you don't have to use `global` if you don't assign to variable new value using `=` . So in first code you have to use `global` because you use `=` to assign `StringVar()` but in second code you don't need global because you change value using `.set()` (and `.get()` doesn't change value)

Comment: if you will keep all in list then you will have only one variable which will need only one `global` when you will create list `entries = []`. but you don't need global when you do `entries.append()` or assign value to element on list `entries[0] = ...`. The same is with `dictionary`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. If your problem is syncing an entry and label widget, all you need is one entry and one label widget, and enough code to make it run.

Comment: Do you want the labels to contain _exactly_ what is in the entry widget? If so, you can give the entry and the label widget the same `StringVar` and they will always be in sync.